# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="http://meta.vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Answer (score 14):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because of her passion for making this a great site from the start. She is active in everything there is, from answering questions with high quality and on-topic answers, through editing content and approving/rejecting it, to managing the whole site with patience and tolerance. She is also active in chat and is a big part of there being a feeling of community even though the site is just few days old.

---

Thanks a lot! I accept the nomination :D I've been looking for a way to do more for veg*n communities for a while, so I'm quite excited about this site.

#### General stuff:

- I currently live in London, and I'm active from around UTC ~0700 until ~1500 most days and often afterwards
- I'm a qualified science teacher but I teach one-to-one instead of in a school, so I have a lot more free time than real teachers

#### Background in the topic:

- Vegetarian for 15 years, vegan for 3 (up to now, and forever), UK Vegan Society life member, always reading articles and talking about veg*nism on and offline...
- Love cooking and been doing it almost every day for 16 years
- Worked in a health food chain store for 3 years and got training in nutrition

#### On Stack Exchange:

- I joined Ask Ubuntu in April last year and got hooked. You can [find me there](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) reviewing, commenting and even answering pretty much all day every day.
- I also occasionally participate in Unix & Linux, and of course I find answers to anything and everything all around the network.

Comment: I see 4 downvotes.. please give reasons for downvoting our best contributor to this site.

Comment: Yes, I would like to hear the reasons from people who downvote as well..

Comment: 4 downvotes? HELL NO....

Comment: @SS. For what it's worth, my nomination also has four downvotes with zero explanation.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I downvoted for 2 reasons. `1)` She and another user tried to hijack [my answer](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/307) because did they not agree with a portion of my answer and the sources I cited in my answer. Now a mod got involved and locked my answer. I believe this is totally unfair. `2)` She tries to make trivial and unwarranted edits such as [this](http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/revisions/409/2) in the name of gender equality and such.

Comment: I agree with all other good things she does on the site, but I just don't feel she's ready to be a moderator. IMO, a moderator doesn't need not be a major contributor on the main site, but needs to know when to get involved and when not get involved in others' questions and answers. Personal tastes of a user need to be suppressed when playing the moderator role.

Comment: @sv. I see your objections and while not of the same opinion, thank you for explaining that. I think your answer was quite nice overall, however, the comments you received on it were rather constructive and would improve it if they were incorporated to it. I can understand why someone does not like the idea of someone else editing his answer, but accepting a suggestion is part of community pages like SE. Anyway, I hope you will have a nice time here at Vegetarianism SE.

Comment: @AlexanderRossa "accepting a suggestion is part of community pages like SE" – Let me give you an example. On of my above comments received 3 upvotes, now I imagine I editing your answer above and put all that junk (yes, I call my own comments junk because they don't belong in the answer) into the answer saying "SE is all about community effort", "accepting suggestions" etc. Now not only will you get irritated but it also calls into question who has the final authority on what goes into an answer on this and other SE sites. (1)

Comment: @AlexanderRossa Who has the final authority on what goes into an answer? IMO, it rests with OP, in this case you. I have no business messing your post especially when you don't agree. Can I downvote and move on? Sure. But repeatedly badgering you to accept my "suggestions" – that IMO is unethical, crossing the line and makes one want to stop participating on the site. A person who doesn't understand all this is unfit to be a moderator, IMHO. (2)

Comment: @sv. That's really worth bringing up either in general meta or a separate meta question here, rather than debating extensively in comments. Deciding site philosophy on edits is valuable for a community, and it's the obligation of moderators to enact that philosophy -- which they're informed of via meta discussion.

Comment: How is everyone surprised by the site's most overzealous editor being downvoted? Thanks for your contribution but I cannot support this nomination for a moderator: this role takes patience, maturity, and respect for the views of others.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I trust Erica to take care of this site's content and users, because of high quality contributions here, especially on meta. It's obvious that Erica is an expert on using Stack Exchange effectively, raising site quality and maintaining a good atmosphere. That's hardly surprising for someone who's already a moderator on two sites, though :)

---

I accept, and thank you!

**Veg*n Experience:** I am a pescatarian. I have a vegetarian teenage daughter, and the majority of my interest in the topic is inspired by her. I have a lot to learn -- and I'm excited by the breadth of experience and perspective that participating here is going to provide me.

**StackExchange Experience:** I have been a *pro tempore* moderator at [Parenting](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4054/erica) for almost two years (April 2015) at [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users/30/erica) for about nine months (May 2016). This gives me a good working knowledge of general StackExchange policy, particularly with regards to background moderation work. I actively strive to keep discussion civil and balanced, and look for constructive ways to provide critcism. ([Be Nice](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) is important, even more so for mods!)

I don't think I'm an *infallible* authority on how StackExchange should work, either in general or specific sites. I therefore believe strongly in the value of Meta discussion for establishing community consensus, and strive for "minimal" moderation (whenever possible, encouraging the community to moderate its own content). Having a strong Meta and well-curated tags are both helpful for a site's health, and I look forward to participating with that whether I'm a moderator or not.

I live in the eastern US, and am active between ~11am and ~1am UTC.

Comment: Moderation of the site is not a cakewalk like some are thinking. Experience in moderation is also a key factor. Erica is also moderator on two other SE sites. So her experience will help the site in maintaining quality. Erica.. Please accept the nomination.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Hi, I'm **Niitaku** and I joined the site at its commitment phase since I didn't know about Area51 before. As I'm a beginner with veganism, I mostly ask questions and I try to answer whenever I can. Like I said in our chatroom (where you can find me almost everyday), I really like this dawning community and I'm very interested in helping it to grow and being more involved. In all my interventions, I do my best to listen to the community feedback (like in [this question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-can-i-determine-how-much-protein-i-need-in-a-vegan-diet) for example) and would obviously continue this if I become moderator.

I would be honored to help this community the best I can and to be a messenger between all of you and the Stack Exchange team.

As I'm living in France, I'm generally available during the day and also in the evening, from 08:00 to 22:00 (UTC).

If you have questions, don't hesitate to ask in the comments! :)

Comment: Will down voter care to comment?

Comment: @Fawad I know it can be upsetting to have a downvote without any explanation, but votes are anonymous by design and nobody can make someone to explain it, it is a right. SE team implemented a _notification_ upon downvote to encourage the user to comment it. From my point of view, it is better to leave a constructive comment to explain the poster what's wrong so that the post can be improved and the author can learn from that feedback.

Comment: May be someone don't want you to become moderator,but atleast they can comment where (s)he can improve…

Comment: @Fawad Here, on the meta, it is a bit special. Community uses the votes to express their opinion, not necessarily to notify something is wrong with the post. In this nomination topic, downvoters say that they don't necessarily see me as moderator and an explanatory comment is not compulsory. This don't imperatively mean there's an issue with my post or that they don't like me.

Answer (score 11):

[image]
[image]

#### Notes:

Hi, I'm Riker.

I joined this site at the commitment phase, I found it from the front page of A51 while trying to search old proposals. Never followed it, and never made any example questions.

I've actually only been a vegetarian for about 2 weeks now.  When the proposal hit public beta, I realized that if that many people actually cared about veg*nism, I should probably give it a shot.

I live in Southern California, about 3 hours (with traffic) inland of LA.  I'm active pretty much all day for me, 6:30 AM PST to 6:00 PM PST (2:30 PM UTC to 2 AM UTC).

I've been around on SE for about a year and a half now.  I currently have around 11.6k rep network wide, mostly on [Programming Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/), [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/),  [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/140963/), and [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/311528/riker).  (interesting note: this site is now my third highest site)

I don't have much rep on any 1 site (4.2k on PPCG, my most), but since Literature just left private beta, and PPCG still hasn't gotten a design (at this point it's got to be some kind of record!) I'm pretty experienced with the high-rep tools.

I'd love to help this community grow!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because …

1. He is very active in the site.
2. Has good editing skills.
3. He asked some interesting question about `vegan diet` and I believe diet is a very important part of this site.
4. His answers seem to be scientific.

So, as a whole he would be good candidate and at least a single moderator should be there who has a sound knowledge about Vegan Diet.

---

I decline this nomination.

Thank you for the nomination and to the people who voted. I am glad to help around the site and see it grow but I cannot accept the position of a moderator. There is a lot of if's and else's in my near future and I would not like to let the community down because of not having time to properly help out and moderate in a few months' time. Good luck to the other nominees and good luck to us all with going public :).

Comment: @AlexanderRossa there's still quite a lot of good to be done as a high-rep community _member_, so keep up the good work :)

Comment: Yes, I plan to do so, just not at the level of commitment that moderation requires. Thanks for the nice words :).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes

This user contributes high-quality answers and questions and has a great objective style, one that I'd personally like to see everywhere on the site. Attilio is aware of what's going on on the site, and takes interest in it.

---

Hi everybody! I'm sorry for not writing before. I'm glad to have been nominated for mod-ing this site. I feel that it's true that I've a deep knowledge of the subject, with plenty of good quality sources, but this doesn't make of me a good mod. Mod qualities are more related to: 1) availability of time (and I can't assure much presence on the site, on the long term), and  2) good understanding of how StackExchange works, and several times I tend to use this site as a discussion forum, posting kind of philosophical and too-wide questions that - for me - are the essence of veganism, that is not a trendy thing, it's a political and interdisciplinary positioning that goes far beyond "how much protein etc..", but of course, this is not the SE way of dealing with the subject.

I feel I can contribute with the site, as I'm doing now: asking loads of questions and answering as better as I can. But I'm not interested in moderating this site (still).

Answer (score -2):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes

Hi there , I am Sagar V.

I were not a member in this community for long time because I didn't knew about it.

The main reason I support vegetarianism is that I care for animals.

I don't like that animals getting killed by people not only for food but also for other things.

Vegetarianism is a good way of life. **Eating meat will make our body a cemetery**

So I support vegetarianism.

The next thing I am telling is that I have good leadership skills.
I am working on an organisation for almost 15 years and so I earned very good leadership skills from the work.

In my country, **India**, Vegetarianism is a part of our region Hindu.

**Also I am ready to accept mistakes and changes**

If I made any mistake and someone pointed it out, I will accept it and correct it without any hesitation.

My primary goal to become a part of this community is to make as much people as I can a Vegan.

Also I am a working professional in an IT company and I can spend almost 5-6 Hrs per day on daytime and 3-4 hrs per day in night time in this community.

Adding, I am an active member of Travel Stack Exchange site [Profile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/57836/sagar-v)

Looking for your opinions.

Regards

[Sagar V](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/57836/sagar-v)

Comment: expecting some suggestion from downvoters.

Comment: It's highly unlikely you'll get some. Meta doesn't work like the main site, you don't get feedback when downvoted the same way. If somebody downvotes you, it means that they don't think you'd be a good mod. That's really it.

Comment: Also, leave your flair the way it is. It's broken due to a change SE as a whole is going through, and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: SE never force downvoter to leave a comment but it is a good practise to leave a comment for downvote so that the person can identify whats wrong with him. @Riker

Comment: I made flair edit based on suggestions from MSE.

Comment: No, that's the point. It's not good practice on meta. They don't think you'd be a good mod, and that's really it. They can leave a comment, sure, but it's not common and/or encouraged as much.

Comment: And don't do that with the flair. Your flair is an automatically updated image, updated to show your current reputation. If you make it an imgur link, it won't update.

Comment: I did not downvote as it did not seem necessary t the time, but if you really want some honest suggestions and opinion as to why you are not fit for the position, I will try:
- Your level of English language is not sufficient for the role. I am not talking about small grammatical mistakes, but about severe problems with the coherency of your thoughts because of it.
- Maybe connected to the first point: I have seen an answer from you where you did not get what the question was asking and offered completely different answer (that was insufficient in its own right).

Comment: - Lack of activity. While you said that you did not know about this site before and that is why you did not participate, at the time that you applied for the role, the election was almost finished (I see moderators were elected already, few hours after you nominated yourself) and it would be really hard to judge your suitability for the position when you have been active for a day or two. Other nominees are people who were here from the day one and helped with what they could. While by no fault of your own, your lack of activity practically "disqualifies" you. These would be my reasons.