# HTTPS Issue in Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed

I would like to mention this link here
[Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site)

While checking that, you can only see flair form main site. Meta flair is not loading.

So I had a look at this https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/378
 which said that **Your connection is not private**

So there is a HTTPS error in meta site.

Comment: @Oded Thanks for your intervention. It is the same problem with other SE sites too. I think you shall focus on that too.

Comment: Thanks @Oded for making a move to more secure environment

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

This has now been resolved. The meta change happened, and now https works.

---

SE knows about this.

If you look at the 'featured on meta', you'll see [something about HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291947/roadmap-to-https-serving-and-uploading-https-images-only?cb=1). That post links to [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345012/155005), which says that this will be fixed soon. They're going to move the meta sites from `meta.site.stackexchange` to `site.meta.stackexchange`, and HTTPS will work then.

EDIT:

Nick Craver (a dev) has explicitly said that this will be fixed then, in the comments [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/money/query/430352/posts-with-inline-http-images-not-from-imgur?StartDate=2009-12-01&EndDate=2017-01-01).