# I set up a @StackVegetarian account on Twitter

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, announcement

For a few years it was common to set up automated Twitter accounts for each StackExchange site that would tweet out new questions as they were asked. However, this practice [ceased in 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/264548/137452) because the StackExchange team saw low engagement numbers through Twitter.

Vegetarianism.SE doesn't have a Twitter bot because we formed in 2017, well after the practice ended. At least, until now...

I set up a new Twitter account called [@StackVegetarian](https://twitter.com/StackVegetarian) with the intention of tweeting out new questions. There is a reasonably large [#vegan](https://hashtagify.me/hashtag/vegan) community on Twitter, so I'm hoping we might be able to attract some traffic from that segment.

#### Rules

I don't have any automation set up right now, it's completely manual. As such, I'm planning to follow several rules.

- Each question will be tweeted exactly once, in the same chronological order that questions are posted to the site. (I have chosen an arbitrary recent [starting point](https://twitter.com/StackVegetarian/status/996448688779051008).)
- No questions will be skipped. All questions will be tweeted.
- Tweets will only be deleted if the corresponding question is deleted. Tweets will stay up even for closed questions.
- The tweet will contain only the question title and a hyperlink (that turns into a [twitter card](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started)). The hyperlink will not contain any user ID.
- If the question title includes the word #vegan or #vegetarian, that will be turned into a hashtag.
- No other tweets will ever be posted. No replies, no retweets, no quote tweets.

#### Future Plans

If the community approves of this, I might set up semi-automatic posting through a service like [Buffer](https://buffer.com/) to space out tweets over time.

If the Stack Exchange community team wants to take over control of the account at any point, I will happily transfer ownership. I'll also happily cede ownership to any [diamond mod](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/110/1236) upon request.

If this ends up being useful but I get tired of maintaining it, I might set up an automatic integration using something like AWS Lambda. (If you know of an easier way to set up automatic posting, let me know!)

Comment: Hm, apparently it is [not okay to use the site logo](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/691/requesting-permission-to-use-the-site-logo-as-the-twitter-accounts-profile-pic).

Comment: I stopped maintaining this a while ago because it really didn't seem worthwhile.